# Stop pyplot.contour from drawing a contour along a discontinuity

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, contour

I have a 2d map of a coordinate transform. The data at each point is the aximuthal angle in the original coordinate system, which goes from 0 to 360. I'm trying to use pyplot.contour to plot lines of constant angle, e.g. 45 degrees. The contour appears along the 45 degree line between the two poles, but there's an additional part to the contour that connects the two poles along the 0/360 discontinuity. This makes a very jagged ugly line as it basically just traces the pixels with a number close to 0 on one side and another close to 360 on the other.

Examples:
Here is an image using full colour map:
[image: colour map with discontinuity]

You can see the discontinuity along the blue/red curve on the left side. One side is 360 degrees, the other is 0 degrees. When plotting contours, I get:

[image: contour plot with discontinuity]

Note that all contours connect the two poles, but even though I have NOT plotted the 0 degree contour, all the other contours follow along the 0 degree discontinuity (because pyplot thinks if it's 0 on one side and 360 on the other, there must be all other angles in between).

Code to produce this data:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

jgal = np.array(
    [
        [-0.054875539726, -0.873437108010, -0.483834985808],
        [0.494109453312, -0.444829589425, 0.746982251810],
        [-0.867666135858, -0.198076386122, 0.455983795705],
    ]
)


def s2v3(rra, rdec, r):
    pos0 = r * np.cos(rra) * np.cos(rdec)
    pos1 = r * np.sin(rra) * np.cos(rdec)
    pos2 = r * np.sin(rdec)
    return np.array([pos0, pos1, pos2])


def v2s3(pos):
    x = pos[0]
    y = pos[1]
    z = pos[2]
    if np.isscalar(x):
        x, y, z = np.array([x]), np.array([y]), np.array([z])
    rra = np.arctan2(y, x)
    low = np.where(rra < 0.0)
    high = np.where(rra > 2.0 * np.pi)
    if len(low[0]):
        rra[low] = rra[low] + (2.0 * np.pi)
    if len(high[0]):
        rra[high] = rra[high] - (2.0 * np.pi)
    rxy = np.sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2)
    rdec = np.arctan2(z, rxy)
    r = np.sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2 + z ** 2)
    if x.size == 1:
        rra = rra[0]
        rdec = rdec[0]
        r = r[0]
    return rra, rdec, r


def gal2fk5(gl, gb):
    rgl = np.deg2rad(gl)
    rgb = np.deg2rad(gb)
    r = 1.0
    pos = s2v3(rgl, rgb, r)

    pos1 = np.dot(pos.transpose(), jgal).transpose()

    rra, rdec, r = v2s3(pos1)

    dra = np.rad2deg(rra)
    ddec = np.rad2deg(rdec)

    return dra, ddec


def make_coords(resolution=50):
    width = 9
    height = 6
    px = width * resolution
    py = height * resolution
    coords = np.zeros((px, py, 4))
    for ix in range(0, px):
        for iy in range(0, py):
            l = 360.0 / px * ix - 180.0
            b = 180.0 / py * iy - 90.0
            dra, ddec = gal2fk5(l, b)
            coords[ix, iy, 0] = dra
            coords[ix, iy, 1] = ddec
            coords[ix, iy, 2] = l
            coords[ix, iy, 3] = b
    return coords


coords = make_coords()

# now do one of these
# plt.imshow(coords[:,:,0],origin='lower') # color plot
plt.contour(
    coords[:, :, 0], levels=[45, 90, 135, 180, 225, 270, 315]
)  # contour plot with jagged ugliness

plt.show()
```

How can I either:

1. stop pyplot.contour from drawing a contour along the discontinuity
2. make pyplot.contour recognize that the 0/360 discontinuity in angle is not a real discontinuity at all.

I can just increase the resolution of the underlying data, but before I get a nice smooth line it starts to take a very long time and a lot of memory to plot.

I will also want to plot a contour along 0 degrees, but if I can figure out how to hide the discontinuity I can just shift it to somewhere else not near a contour. Or, if I can make #2 happen, it won't be an issue.

Comment: It would help if you could post an image of the problem plot, or some example code to produce a (simplified) version.

Comment: I just added example plots to illustrate the problem

Comment: This is a strange use of contours and I do not think you are going to be able to make it work the way you want.  I am, however confident that you can get the plot you want using something other than contour.  Using `imshow` will give you something like your top plot and `streamplot` will give you something close to your bottom plot.  Which plot is closer to what you ultimately want?  Could you supply a function that produces the data field so we have something to play with?

Comment: @GJP The function is not passing along a discontinuity, it is the end of a period, see answer below...

Comment: The first plot is imshow, but I only use that to show you where the discontinuity is. I will have to look at streamplot but it doesn't look like it's quite what I need.

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely still a hack, but you can get nice smooth contours with a two-fold approach:

1. Plot contours of the absolute value of the phase (going from -180˚ to 180˚) so that there is no discontinuity.
2. Plot two sets of contours in a finite region so that numerical defects close to the tops and bottoms of the extrema do not creep in.

Here is the complete code to append to your example:

```
Z = np.exp(1j*np.pi*coords[:,:,0]/180.0)
Z *= np.exp(0.25j*np.pi/2.0)   # Shift to get same contours as in your example
X = np.arange(300)
Y = np.arange(450)

N = 2
levels = 90*(0.5 + (np.arange(N) + 0.5)/N)
c1 = plt.contour(X, Y, abs(np.angle(Z)*180/np.pi), levels=levels)
c2 = plt.contour(X, Y, abs(np.angle(Z*np.exp(0.5j*np.pi))*180/np.pi), levels=levels)
```

[image: Smooth contour plot of phase angle]

One can generalize this code to get smooth contours for any "periodic" function.  What is left to be done is to generate a new set of contours *with the correct values* so that colormaps apply correctly, labels will be applied correctly etc.  However, there does not seem to be a simple way of doing this with matplotlib: the relevant `QuadContourSet` class does everything and I do not see a simple way of constructing an appropriate contour object from the contours `c1` and `c2`.

Answer (score 0):

I was interested in the exact same problem. One solution is to `NaN` out the contours along the branch cut; see [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/20548); another is to use the `max_jump` argument in [matplotx's contour()](https://github.com/nschloe/mplx#contour-plots-for-functions-with-discontinuities).

I molded the solution into a Python package, [cplot](https://github.com/nschloe/cplot).

```py
import cplot
import numpy as np


def f(z):
    return np.exp(1 / z)


cplot.show(f, (-1.0, +1.0, 400), (-1.0, +1.0, 400))
```

[image]